# Speedy Https redirection

Tags: apache

I'm presently using htaccess to force redirection to https for my website but I'm finding that redirected traffic is taking >1.5 seconds longer to receive the first file from the server than direct to https traffic.

What is the fastest way to force https for the whole site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `.htaccess` is the fastest way to force https.

This is because `.htaccess` is a configuration on the web server (Apache), which is the first system to receive the `http` request.

```
Browser => DNS => Load Balancer => Web Server => Application
```

You could also force https at the application level but it would mean you have to go thru the server first. Unless you are using a load balancer, the web server is the first point contact a browser has with your `https` rules.

Of course, the fastest way would be to make sure all the links you are sending are in `https` so that the user never goes thru a redirect (`301`).